# How to update options changed in UI of jQgrid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

Hi i am trying to add one additional attribute to an select box for my requirement on initialization. Everything working fine but the options are not updated in UI. The last updated value is been over-riding all the other options model data.

Here is my code below:

**ColModelData format options looks like below:**

```
"colModel": [
        {"name":'cityName',"index":'cityName',"width":90,"editable": true,"edittype":"select","formatter":selectFormatter,"editoptions":{"value":"TN:Tamilnadu;AP:Andhrapradesh;MP:MAdhyapradesh",
"class":"select2","width":400}},
```

**SelectFormatter function looks like this**

```
var global=1;

function selectFormatter(cellvalue, options, rowObject){
        global++;       
        var cellvalueArr = cellvalue.split('($)');
        var val =   cellvalueArr[0];
        var newCellvalue = cellvalueArr[1];
        var rowId = options.rowId;
        options.colModel.editoptions.dbVal=global; // trying to update the options of row dynamically 
        //console.log("\noptions => "+JSON.stringify(options)+"\ncellvalue => "+cellvalue + "\ndbVal => "+val+"\nrowId => "+rowId); // output in console
        return cellvalue; // return the cellName not value for Selectoptions
    }
```

So the below screenshot output will let you know what is the problem i am facing:

[image]

By this screenshot you can see the options value are updating.

The below 2nd screenshot defines the last option value is been updated to all the options list in UI that is overridden.

[image]

So how to update the same in UI corresponding to the data changed?